# Calling c++ function from delphi

Tags: c++, delphi, dll

I wrote a DLL in C++ whose functions will be called from a Delphi application.

One of the functions in the DLL takes a `Pointer` to a buffer where an XML string should be written.  But, when I write a string into the buffer, after returning from the function the application crashes with an "Access violation at address 0048B... in module ....exe. Write of address 3030D..." error.

The calling convention of the function declarations are the same, both in the DLL and the application.

I've made a simple application in Delphi to simulate the behavior of the application and it works fine.  The biggest problem is that I don't have any information about the application internals: no sources, no documents, not even logs. Just function declarations and parameter descriptions.

Function declaration in delphi:

```
function functionName(var Buffer: Pointer; var BuffLen: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
```

Function Declaration in the DLL:

```
extern "C" int WINAPI functionName(char*, int*);
```

Does someone know how to solve this?

From my tests, I have a feeling that the problem is in the application, not in the DLL.  However, I'm not completely sure about this.  Are there any possible tests I can do at the DLL site to either solve the problem or locate the issue?

I'd really appreciate any help in this matter.

As a side note, the DLL is compiled with Visual Studio. Can this cause the problem?

Comment: Where is the memory for the buffer allocated?

Comment: Without some code of how the application is calling to the function, it's going to be difficult to determine where the problem is. Perhaps show the code that works

Comment: The memory is allocated in application side @RichardCritten

Comment: As for the call of a function, we don't have application source codes, so no idea how the call is performed. @DaveNottage

Comment: @Sargis You don't need the application source code. You just need to translate the DLL declarations *correctly* (which you are not).

Comment: @Remy That's still not enough to know *how* to call the function. For instance, int* could be a pointer to single value or pointer to array, and could be optional. It's impossible to know. Which is why this question has no definitive answer without guesswork.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DLL function you showed is declared wrong in your Delphi code.  `var Buffer: Pointer` is equivilent to `void**` in C, or `void*&` in C++, but certainly not to `char*` like the DLL function is expecting.  Using a `void**`/`void*&` parameter would be useful if the DLL were allocating memory to return to the application, but from your description that is not the case.

Use this Delphi declaration instead:

```
function functionName(Buffer: PAnsiChar; var BuffLen: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
```

`PAnsiChar` in Delphi is equivalent to `char*` in C/C++.

You should read the following blog article about the gotchas to watch out for when converting C/C++ declarations to Delphi:

[Rudy's Delphi Corner: Pitfalls of converting](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html)

Comment: Technically, isn't `var Buffer: Pointer` equivalent to `void*&` or `void&*` (can't figure out the order of the two modifiers). `void**` would be `Buffer: PPointer` (where PPointer = `^POINTER`).

Comment: @HeartWare the order is `void*&`, and yes, you are right, from a C++ perspective. From a C perspective, it is `void**`.

Comment: And even in C++, `void**` will work fine. So tht would be my preferred translation. But `unsigned char **` would probably work too (same binary representation) and would probably be easier to use in the DLL.

Comment: Anyway, translation is the art of failure. ;-)